# why pywinauto with backend uia can not recognize some qt element?

Tags: qt, pywinauto

with pywinauto version 0.6.5, i try to automate some qt button click. after connecting to app window, print_ctrl_ids display something irrelevant controls excluding button.

```
|
| TitleBar - ''    (L598, T165, R1340, B184)
| [u'', u'1', u'0', 'TitleBar']
|    |
|    | Menu - '系统'    (L580, T165, R598, B183)
|    | [u'Menu', u'\u7cfb\u7edfMenu', u'\u7cfb\u7edf', u'\u7cfb\u7edf1', u'\u
b\u7edf0']
|    | child_window(title="系统", auto_id="MenuBar", control_type="MenuBar")
|    |    |
|    |    | MenuItem - '系统'    (L580, T165, R598, B183)
|    |    | [u'\u7cfb\u7edfMenuItem', u'MenuItem', u'\u7cfb\u7edf2']
|    |    | child_window(title="系统", control_type="MenuItem")
|    |
|    | Button - '关闭'    (L1321, T164, R1341, B184)
|    | [u'\u5173\u95edButton', 'Button', u'\u5173\u95ed']
|    | child_window(title="关闭", control_type="Button")
|
| Custom - ''    (L580, T184, R1340, B853)
| ['Custom', u'Custom0', u'2', u'Custom1']
|    |
|    | Custom - ''    (L580, T184, R1340, B853)
|    | ['Custom', u'Custom0', u'2', u'Custom1']
|    |    |
|    |    | Custom - ''    (L580, T184, R1340, B514)
|    |    | [u'4', 'Custom3']
|    |    |    |
|    |    |    | Custom - ''    (L580, T461, R1340, B514)
|    |    |    | [u'5', 'Custom4']
|    |    |    |    |
|    |    |    |    | Custom - ''    (L652, T461, R1268, B514)
|    |    |    |    | [u'6', 'Custom5']
|    |    |
|    |    | Custom - ''    (L652, T550, R1098, B569)
|    |    | [u'7', 'Custom6']
|    |    |
|    |    | Custom - ''    (L652, T589, R1098, B647)
|    |    | [u'8', 'Custom7']
|    |    |
|    |    | Custom - ''    (L1158, T550, R1268, B660)
|    |    | [u'9', 'Custom8']
|    |    |
|    |    | Custom - ''    (L1158, T662, R1268, B710)
|    |    | [u'10', 'Custom9']
```

Comment: Can `Inspect.exe` see this button? Is it toolbar button? `Inspect.exe` may find it by mouse hovering, but this button has no parents. If this is the case, we're working on the workaround.